# Подсчет количества обменов и сравнений в пузырку

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(){
int array1[1000];
int array2[10000];
int array3[100000];
int m = 1000;
int n = 10000;
int f = 100000;



bad(array1, m);
bad(array2, n);
//bad(array3, f);
best(array1, m);
best(array2, n);
//best(array3, f);
random(array1, m);
random(array2, n);
//random(array3, f);








}
int bad(int array[], int g){
    int i;
for(i=g;i>0;i--){
    array[i] = i;

}
sort(array,g);
return 1;
}
int best(int array[], int g){
    int i;
for(i=0;i<=g;i++){
    array[i] = i;

}
    sort(array,g);
return 1;
}
int random(int array[], int g){
int i;
for(i=0;i<=g;i++){
array[i] = rand()%1000;

}
sort(array,g);

return 1;
}
int sort(int a[], int g){
int i;
int j;  
long int compare;
long int copy;



for(i = 0 ; i < g - 1; i++) { 

   for(j = 0 ; j < g - i - 1 ; j++) {  
        compare++;
       if(a[j] > a[j+1]) {           

          int tmp = a[j];
          a[j] = a[j+1] ;
          a[j+1] = tmp; 
          copy++;
       }
    }

}
printf("copy = %d\n", copy);
printf("compare = %d\n\n",compare);

return 1;
}
```

**Неверно считает количество обменов**
для массива 1000 элементов в худшем случае выдает 5 обменов 499500 сравнений

Answer (score 2):

Программа ничего не считает. В языке С не допускается вызов необъявленных функций. В вашем же коде попытки вызывать необъявленные функции делаются повсеместно.

В любом случае, результаты любого "счета" будут бессмысленны: переменные `compare` и `copy` никак не инициализированы и содержат мусор. Это не говоря уже о том, что вы пытаетесь печатать значения типа `long int` через спецификатор формата `%d`.

Также, в языке С максимально допустимым индексом в массиве размера `N` является индекс `N-1`. Ваши функции `bad`, `best` и `random` при изначальном заполнении массивов нагло вылезают за допустимый диапазон индексов.

Также не ясно, о каком "худшем случае" вы говорите. У вас и функция `bad`, и функция `best` одинаково заполняют массив уже отсортированными по возрастанию значениями. Т.е. сортировать ни там, ни там ничего не надо. С той только разницей, что функция `bad`, оправдывая свое название, умудряется оставить мусор в нулевом элементе массива. Из-за этого мусора в варианте `bad` и могут получиться какие-то непредсказуемые несчастные перестановки.